# Ballerina Facebook Connector - Unable to create a facebook client

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I am using ballerina facebook connector. I have configured the following in my code. The access token is retrieved through facebook Graph API explorer v3.2.

```
import ballerina/io;
import wso2/facebook;
import ballerina/http;

facebook:FacebookConfiguration facebookConfig = {
    clientConfig:{
        auth:{
            scheme: http:OAUTH2,
            accessToken:"AccessTokenRetrieved"
        }
    }
};

function getPageAccessTokens(facebook:Client facebookclient) {
    io:println("-----------------Requesting page access token------------------");
    var response = facebookclient->getPageAccessTokens("userid");
}

public function main(){
    facebook:Client facebookclient = new(facebookConfig);
   getPageAccessTokens(facebookclient);
}
```

The code is compiling but the facebookclient is empty. But when I directly call the facebook endponit a facebook client is successfully created.

```
    public function main(){

    http:Client clientEP = new("https://graph.facebook.com/pageid?fields=access_token&access_token=AccessTokenRetrieved");

    var resp = clientEP->get("");
    if (resp is http:Response) {
        var payload = resp.getTextPayload();
        if (payload is string) {
            io:println(payload);
        } else {
            io:println(<string> payload.detail().message);
        }
    } else {
        io:println(<string> resp.detail().message);
    }
}
```

What is wrong in my first implementation that use ballerina facebook connector?